# jQuery.append() 1.8.3 vs 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some DOM manipulation which doesn't work with `1.7.2`, but is working with `1.8.3`

`1.8.3` http://jsfiddle.net/6Nyqd/

`1.7.2` http://jsfiddle.net/6Nyqd/1/

(throws error `An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`)

**UPDATE:**
What should I change so it will work with `1.7.x+` versions of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to [1.8](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) the append method was not accepting an array as an argument

See [this bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11231)

---

As a solution you can deal with an array of dom elements like

```
var options = "text for li";
var $ul = $(".loto_stat");

var $template = $ul.first().children().first();
var $domel = $.map(options.split(''), function (el) {
    return $template.clone().show().data("brojevi", el)
        .find(".text").text(el).end().get(0);
});

$ul.append($domel);
```

Demo: [1.8](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k5M6p/1/), [1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k5M6p/2/), [1.9](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k5M6p/3/), [1.10](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k5M6p/4/)

---

Why your query is not working, the `map()` function is returning jQuery objects so `$domel` is an array of jQuery object which is not supported in jQuery 1.7, but an array of dom elements are supported.

---

The problem with 1.9/1.10 is not with append, it is with passing a string to `$.map()` you need to pass an array so use `options.split('')`

Comment: +1, same thing, it works for 1.8 and 1.7 but not for 1.9 and 1.10?

Answer (score 1):

Before jQuery 1.8, you can't append an array of jQuery objects.

You could do with:

```
$.each($domel, function(_, e) {$ul.append(e);});
```

The reason you said not work for 1.9 and 1.10 is because you use a string for `$.map`, it's now need an array.

so change

```
$.map(options,
```

to

```
$.map(options.split(''),
```

Comment: +1, it works for 1.8 and 1.7 but not for 1.9 and 1.10

Comment: Does multiple `.append()` to DOM have significant impact on performance?